# How to bypass latest MS Excel security annoyance?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007

Right off the bat let me say that I open this Excel file only on my home desktop computer. The file has some script that populates the table with the stock prices off the Internet. So every time I open it up and enter my password I get this window, that is a classic Microsoft: It has a lot of text, needs several selections to continue, and requires scrolling.

[image]

Since I'm the only one who's using this desktop, is there any way to set up Excel so that it opens this specific file without this security warning?

I basically need these two boxes checked:

[image]

PS. I obviously want to keep this warning for any other XLS files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sign the macro in your Excel file with a [digital self-signing certificate](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx). When opening the signed file for the first time, Excel would ask you to approve the source of the file (i.e. you) and after the approval it will not show the warnings anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice. Just signed it and that window is gone. One issue still remains though. When I open up that XLSM file it shows "Security Warning: Data connections have been disabled" on top that I need to click on, and then confirm by checking "enable this content" and click OK. Still too many steps. Is there any way to cut these with a signature?

Comment: try adding the site you're downloading your data from to the `Trusted Sites` in Internet Explorer